# How to unroll multiple Flux and keep the originals?

Tags: java, project-reactor, flatmap

I want to generate an interleaved stream of two objects types.

I have the two helper methods

- `Aaa genAaa()` (or `Mono<Aaa>`?) to create one `Aaa` and
- `Flux<Bbb> genBbbs(Aaa a)` to create a set of `Bbb`s from to `a`.

The overall result should be a `Flux<JsonNode>` to accomodate the mixing of the two objects types.

So, the result would be something like

```
[ {'name':'Aaa-X'}, 
    {'name':'Bbb-x1'},
    {'name':'Bbb-x2'},
  {'name':'Aaa-Y'},
    {'name':'Bbb-y1'},
    {'name':'Bbb-y2'},
    {'name':'Bbb-y3'}
]
```

As a rough sketch I tried this:

```
final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

public Flux<JsonNode> create() {
  return Flux.range(0, 2)       // create 2
    .map( idx -> genAaa() )     // bare Aaa's
    .flatMap( a -> genBbbs(a) ) // bare Aaa to Flux<Bbb> ???
    .map( om::valueToTree );    // anything to JsonNode
}
```

But I have several one big issue here:

Because I transform the `Aaa` objects (and thus consume them) they are not in the result anymore. I have no idea how I can "use" and keep them in this scenario.

I was thinking if I could pass the "flux in progress" as a parameter to the generate functions, so they each add `JsonNodes` as they are created, but that feels wrong (totally not-async) and I wouldn't now how anyway. I suppose there is a concept in Fluxes that just eludes me, still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Flux#concat`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) together with `genBbbs` method inside the function passed to the `flatMap`:

```java
private static Flux<JsonNode> combine() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return Flux.concat(getAaa("a0"), getAaa("a1"))// Flux<Aaa>
            .flatMap(aaa -> Flux.concat(Mono.just(aaa), getBbbs(aaa))) // Flux<Object>
            .map(objectMapper::valueToTree); // Flux<JsonNode>
}
```

the `concat` method simply concatenates two sources:

1. Artificially created using [`Mono.just`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#just-T-)
2. The `Flux<B>` from the `getBbbs(aaa)` invocation

Example output:

```
{"name":"a0"}
{"name":"B1-a0"}
{"name":"B2-a0"}
{"name":"a1"}
{"name":"B1-a1"}
{"name":"B2-a1"}
```

---

*Full listing*:

```java
public class Main {
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    private static class Aaa {
        private String name;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    private static class Bbb {
        private String name;
    }

    private static Mono<Aaa> getAaa(String name) {
        return Mono.just(new Aaa(name));
    }

    private static Flux<Bbb> getBbbs(Aaa aaa) {
        return Flux.just(new Bbb("B1-" + aaa.getName()), new Bbb("B2-" + aaa.getName()));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        combine().subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Flux<JsonNode> combine() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return Flux.concat(getAaa("a0"), getAaa("a1"))// Flux<Aaa>
                .flatMap(aaa -> Flux.concat(Mono.just(aaa), getBbbs(aaa))) // Flux<Object>
                .map(objectMapper::valueToTree); // Flux<JsonNode>
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitily learned a lot looking at your solution. I will apply it to my brain and my concrete code and will come back to this.